# Resource info value is empty using GetGlobalResourceObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo, culture

I create a resx file called Resource.fr-FR with the below entry for France

**

```
Name       Value
Greeting   Bonjour
```

**

I then execute the code on page load with the culture set as `fr-FR`

```
lblvalue.Text = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "Greeting");
```

but it always defaults to the English (default Hello text).

I then tried

```
var FrenchCulture= new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = FrenchCulture;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = FrenchCulture;
```

`lblvalue.Text = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "Greeting", FrenchCulture);`

but this time i get

```
No overload for method 'GetGlobalResourceObject' takes 3 arguments
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change Current Culture of the current Thread rather than Default Culture of the Default Thread.-

```
  var FrenchCulture= new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = FrenchCulture;
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = FrenchCulture;
```